# android: cleaning up memory on app destroy

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developing an app which instantiates a bunch of bitmap objects (e.g. buttons, which have cache bitmaps, so they don't have to get rendered again and again)

Now, I realised that when I run and start the app repeatedly on my huawei mobile device, I get an OutOfMemoryException at a point where the app tries to allocate some memory for the bitmaps.
So I guess it's the bitmaps which make trouble. I do know that there is a bitmap.recycle() method though.

Now my question: what is best practice to clean up memory?
Why isn't there some View method like View::onDestroy() which can be implemented for cleanup purpose?

EDIT: example

my "CirclyButton" (extends Button) class always draws a cached bitmap onDraw:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.getDefaultBitmap(), 0, 0, paint);
    }
    private Bitmap getDefaultBitmap(){
        if(mBitmapDefault == null){
            mBitmapDefault = Bitmap.createBitmap(8*radius, 8*radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmapDefault);
            this.drawDefault(canvas);
            return mBitmapDefault;
        }
        return mBitmapDefault;
    }
```

So I guess this allocated data should be recycled somewhere...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views don't have an `onDestroy` method because views usually don't get destroyed, activities do. A view won't just be destroyed if nothing happens to its activity (Unless you inflate a different layout... That's not the case, right?), and if something happens to its activity, you do have a callback getting called.

If there is a `recycle()` method, make sure you call it. And remove *all* reference to memory taking objects in the `onDestroy`, i.e:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    object1 = null;
    object2 = null;
    //...
}
```

So the GC can do its job. I had the same problem with the `AdView` of AdMob, although they did have a `destroy` method it didn't really help. But deleting my references of the view fixed the problem.

Comment: but there has to be some convenient way of doing that. just think of how many buttons there may be...

Comment: So store them in an array and iterate over them. Are these created in layout or by code?

Comment: Well, if you store them in a list/array or keep track of their states, it makes things easier. The most important thing is, **never** keep static references unless you make *sure* you dispose them. Keeping a static reference to a `Context` could lead to the worst ever memory leak.

Comment: What is a static reference? can you give me an example?

Comment: A static reference is any static field in a class. A static field is a field declared with the word `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Provide more information about where are you using your bitmaps, i have some serious experience of working with images and saving memory.

For example in my app i have a list of some data, which display some bitmap in each row. I store my list in a fragment(for fragment support i use compatibility library), and i recycled my bitmaps on this fragment onDestroy method.

Later i decided to optimize my list, so i added scroll listener to my list and started recycling bitmaps, when they are scrolled off the screen.

Comment: Ok, so now just tell me where are you using this button, in some layout of a fragment or activity? Best thing i can suggest you for now is to recycle this images when activity or fragment that holds it is going onDestroy

Comment: Define some method like recycle() in your viewgroup that will recycle all resources...or if you fill yourself a strong developer, change your viewgroup so it will recycle images of buttons which are not displayed at the moment. And then get these images from SD card when they will be needed again, it should not be a longterm operation.