# Android-activities continue to use RAM memory even if they are left

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-studio, ram

For several months I am creating an application for Android and I have a problem I can not solve : my application unexpectedly crashes after a few minutes of use. Thanks to the " Memory Monitor " of Android Studio, I can see that my application is using more and more memory over time : when I change activity , memory usage increases but not decreases, which then causes the stoppage my application when any memory allocated to it is used (256 MB) .

Do you have a solution to ensure that the memory used ceases to steadily increase over time as if already vacated activities continued to use memory ?

Here is a screenshot of Memory Monitor , phases rising with red arrows correspond to the launch of various activities. The blue arrow indicates when the application leaves unexpectedly.[image: Memory Monitor Android Studio]

Comment: release the memory on `onDestroy`

Comment: Are you using any 3th party library?

Comment: I just use Unity Ads SDK

Comment: Maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759601/proper-ondestroy-how-to-avoid-memory-leaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting your new Activity, set its Intent flags like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent .setFlags(intent .getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i);
```

or add `android:noHistory="true"` to the setting of your activity in manifest.
This way force an activity to be added to the history stack.

Also you can clean up your memory in `onDestory` take a look at this link :

[android-cleaning-up-memory-on-app-destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870715/android-cleaning-up-memory-on-app-destroy)

Comment: How is related `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` to memory leaks?

Comment: @omainegra whenever you go to new activity , previous activity store in back stack so it takes memory .By using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` you tell your app that do not store activities in back stack(memory)

Comment: And how is supposed to go back in history if you clear it. The problem is somewhere else, I have apps with 5 to 6 activities in history and never got a memory leak.

Comment: it will clear when android app goes to background it will kill my activity....for this wat can i do????